# WiX: How to execute a command line command after installation

Tags: wix, installation, custom-action

I need to register an HTTP port after installation, but I guess this could be abstracted to generally executing any command line command. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<CustomAction Id="ExecPortOpen" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand="cmd.exe &quot;netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=Everyone&quot;" Return="ignore" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="ExecPortOpen" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This just opens a command prompt mid-install and does nothing with it. I've tried adding /c (I have no idea what it does) inbetween cmd.exe and the command but that just opens and closes the command prompt without executing the command. How do I make this work? I'm using WiX 3.8.

Comment: FYI, there will be a new Http extension for registering an HTTP port in WiX v3.10/4.0.  http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4505/

Answer (score 29):

Solved myself, was actually an UAC/ permissions issue. For any interested parties here is the working code:

```
<CustomAction Id="ExecPortOpen" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="commit" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /c &quot;netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=Everyone&quot;" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ExecPortOpen" After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: I searched so much all over the net, and you're the first that I found who pointed out that `Execute="commit"` will preserve UAC for `netsh` while `Execute="immediate"` runs in user mode.  Thanks!

Comment: the Impersonate="no" did the trick, FYI [link](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-cmd-exe-from-a-CustomAction-td696703.html)

Comment: I know we avoid useless comments but... THANK YOU @Weatherman159 !!